# Can't find /_styles/ folder in Sharepoint Designer 2010

Tags: sharepoint, styles, directory

I have 2 SharePoint Server 2010 on different physical servers.

I made some customization in corev4.css and in v4 masterpage (with sharepoint designer) on the first sever.

And now i want copy my customization, but on second server when i connect through sharepoint designer i can't find /_styles/ folder, and  corev4.css generally.

Any idea?

Thanks! (sorry for my Eng)

Answer (score 1):

The physical path is in %programfiles%\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\1033\STYLES

If you want to deploy it, you can create a sp2010 solution in visual studio, right click your project, Add > SharePoint Mapped Folder, select {root}\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\1033\STYLES, put your custom css there, and finally build and deploy it.